# Close a dropdown component on body click

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js, I don't think it matters what lib I'm using though, just one that allows you to have web components. Anyway - I have a dropdown component (see code below), and I need to know, how do I close the dropdown on body click? If it is a component that has its own scoped data, I'm assuming you can't just add an event listener to the body, it's out of scope, right? How would I go about this?

dropdown.template.html

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" tabindex="1" v-on="click: toggleDropdown($event), keydown: closeDropdown($event) | key 'esc'"><content select=".dropdown__button"></content></a>
</li>

<ul class="dropdown__menu" v-show="displayed">
    <content select=".menu"></content>
</ul>
```

dropdown.js

```
module.exports = {
  template: require('../views/dropdown.template.html'),

  data: function() {
    return {
      displayed: false
    };
  },

  methods: {
    toggleDropdown: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      this.displayed = !this.displayed;
    },

    closeDropdown: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      this.displayed = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `blur` event:

```
<a href="#" tabindex="1" v-on="click: toggleDropdown($event), keydown: closeDropdown($event) | key 'esc', blur: closeDropdown($event)"><content select=".dropdown__button"></content></a>
```

Comment: Ah, of course, so simple. This does get in the way of accessibly tabbing through the dropdown list correct? Should I make a new question or if you could point me in the right way that'd be great. Thanks!